# Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the development logs I am getting this message:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes for Message: notification_id, receiver_id, conversation_id
    app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:21:in `create'
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:13:in `user_time_zone'
```

I am wondering how I can correct this as I am using rails 4. I have tried adding to the `attr_accessible` in the User model but that does not make a difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:You need to add your `attr_accessible` to your Message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :notification_id, :receiver_id, :conversation_id
end
```

Comment: That's what I figured but since the gem I am using `mailboxer` does not require or use a Message model I was a little confused and wanted to avoid creating something that the gem doesn't use. Having a messages model will confuse things, since what I use is a Notifications table, not Messages.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the gem, but you're likely looking to build a subclass of the Message model, or (even more likely) a decorator model by which you would place your `attr_accessible` code in.

Comment: Looking at your controller code, it appears as though you're calling `current_user.messages`. That means you must have a `has_many` or some variation within your User model, which means you are pointing to a model(Message) from there. I would track back through that association to find what model you're referencing and then override that model and re-link your `has_many` to your subclassed model. Or in the event we're dealing with a decorator, just maintain the same association and fulfill your `attr_accessible` in there.